# Atmega328P is not responding in avrdude using usbasp

Tags: arduino, atmega, avrdude, usbasp

I have a cheap Chinese USBASP clone and it works fine with my ATtiny13A, but I always get this:

```
avrdude: auto set sck period (because given equals null)
avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
```

This is not actually a problem, because I successfully programmed my ATtiny13A several times, also using a -B 250 argument when my fuses were set to a lower clock speed, so my USBASP definitely works.
But now I want to program my ATmega328P and I get this:

```
avrdude: auto set sck period (because given equals null)
avrdude: warning: cannot set sck period. please check for usbasp firmware update.
avrdude: error: programm enable: target doesn't answer. 1 
avrdude: initialization failed, rc=-1
     Double check connections and try again, or use -F to override
     this check.
```

I do not know what the fuses are of this chip, I changed it some time ago and now I can't even read them. I tried to connect a crystal to the atmega, and I also tried without any crystals and nothing worked. Can this chip be dead? I don't think I applied high voltages to it.
(How) can I fix it?
Please help me.

Comment: "an this chip be dead?" never change fuses and not remember/know what you did. It's most likely unrecoverable. who knows what it wants on the crystal now?! ATMEGA328P can be horrible things to flash/burn fuses for, make sure you are well prepared...

Comment: Get your usbasp updated. The firmware can be found online and is compatible. Borrow a friend's usbasp if you have to. Once that's done, you can change sck to a really slow clock. If you cannot update, see if the usbasp has solder jumpers, headers. Some versions can be set to slow by shorting the jumper. If that falls, try to directly drive xtal1

Comment: I can successfully slow the sck on my usbasp, I already did it with my ATtiny13A, but with my ATmega328P it still gives the "programm enable: target doesn't answer. 1" error.

Comment: This is perhaps a lesson in why it is a good idea to avoid the "cheap Chinese" devices. I recommend the pocket AVR programmer from Sparkfun. I have not had any problems with it thus far, and best of all it is still quite cheap. https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9825

Comment: You can try applying 1MHz clock to XTAL1 pin.

Comment: How can I get a 1MHz clock? I don't have a 1MHz crystal or anything like that. Maybe with another arduino board, I heard that it is possible to generate a clock with an output pin, but I have no idea how.

Comment: You can grab a second AVR and run it from the internal 1MHz oscillator (not accurate, but good enough). The code is pretty simple: `DDRB |= 1 << PINB0; while(1) PORTB ^= 1 << PINB0;`

Comment: This will toggle `PINB0` as fast as possible. Although the frequency will be less than 500kHz, it might be sufficient for the chip to start up.

Comment: it all depends on what the fuses were set to, as to if it will even be looking for an external crystal/clock source. The "rc=-1" error encompasses so many possible failures it's extremely difficult to debug the true cause. I have had this many times for many different reasons, it's ridiculous. It can be power related, reset signal related, clock/fuse settings, something on the SPI bus interfering with signals, and plenty more. Because you have successfully used the USBASP on other devices, just move on to debug something else. I have a "cheap" chinese USBASP and it works better than real shit

Comment: I have used my shitty USBASP to program 120 different ATMEGA328Ps in a remote sensor network commissioning project. At various points I had rc=-1 errors, not from the USBASP. It can be the wiring between the USBASP and the ATMEGA though, so make sure the pins are all properly connected. Your AT Tiny13A is hard to get wrong, there arent many pins.